# Auto Update Data Validation in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, auto-update, validation

I have a google spreadsheet that has columns that contain drop downs populated using data validation and another tab on the spreadsheet. I need these to auto update whenever something new is added to one of the spreadsheets that feed the main sheet with drop downs options so that I do not have to reset the validation each time. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

say you have a list of stuff B1:B10 that you want other data cells to validate against. instead of setting the validation to B1:B10, set it to B1:B100. this will accommodate the addition of new values, because blank cells are not used.